# Is this the Ninth sister in Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

While watching a recently released [Star Wars Jedi: Fallen Order trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfcAHfDuNzw), I thought I saw an Imperial (with a lightsaber) with striking likeness to the Ninth Sister:
[image: Picture taken at 1:24 in trailer]

**Is this the Ninth Sister, or another Imperial of the same species?**

Comment: @Lexible I am aware of what I have linked. The second link is when the character appears on screen (the video starts at the given time.)

Comment: @Lexible I've removed one of the links

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/new-star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-trailer-highlights), this is indeed the **Ninth Sister**. (emphasis mine)

> Meet the **Ninth Sister**.
>  
> As if the Second Sister wasn’t bad enough. We only catch a glimpse of this **hulking Inquisitor**, and she looks like a more than formidable threat for our heroes.
> <sub>SOURCE: [6 HIGHLIGHTS FROM THE NEW STAR WARS JEDI: FALLEN ORDER TRAILER](https://www.starwars.com/news/new-star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-trailer-highlights)</sub>

[image]

---

<sub>The linked article was written by Dan Brooks, Lucasfilm’s senior content strategist of online and the editor of [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com).</sub>